# Measure of a set where the density is zero, has measure zero.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, lebesgue-measure

Suppose I have a probability distribution $\mu(x)$ with density $p(x)$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure. I have been told (but not sure) that the set
$$
A = \{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\,:\, p(x) = 0\}
$$
has measure zero. **However** I have not been told with respect to what measure. It could be with respect to $\mu$ or with respect to the Lebesgue measure (the base measure).

My guess is that $\mu(A) =0$ but $\lambda(A)$ doens't need to be. If so, is it possible to prove $\mu(A) = 0$?

Comment: Well, $$\mu(A)=\int_A \mu(dx)=\int_A p(x) \lambda(dx).$$ Now use the definition of $A$.

Comment: Your guess is correct. For a proof see first comment on your answer.

Comment: Note that for any $p\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with $p\geq 0$, then $$\mu(dx)=p(x)\lambda(dx)$$ gives a probability measure. For example if $p=1_{[0,1]^n}$, then $A$ has infinite Lebesgue measure. On the other hand, if $p$ is a gaussian, then $A$ has Lebesgue measure equal to zero.